# The using statement used with a font

Tags: c#, using

I have this example for a method that responds to the paint event. My question is regarding the using of the using statement. What is so special about a font that it is put in the using statement? I understand if it was a stream or something else where it would be automatically closed. But why use it here? Is it so the font will be disposed?

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font font = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), 28, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    {
        Point point1 = new Point(10,10);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Banner Text", font, point1, Color.Blue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `using` statement is *always* so that X (where X is whatever type is assigned in the `()` part) is disposed. That is its raison d'etre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used this way to ensure that the Font is properly disposed of.

From [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> File and Font are examples of managed types that access unmanaged
>   resources (in this case file handles and device contexts). There are
>   many other kinds of unmanaged resources and class library types that
>   encapsulate them. All such types must implement the IDisposable
>   interface.